# Parametric function

Tags: functions

> $$\begin{cases}
> x(t)=\sin ^2 t\\
> y(t)=\cot ^2 t\\
> \end{cases}
> $$

I need to explore this function, but I can't find enough information in my language. I don't know the steps of exploring the parametric function and building the graphic. I'd like to learn how to explore such a function in parametric form.

Comment: What do you mean by "i cant find enough information in my language. I dont "

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

$$x=\sin ^2 t,y=\cot ^2 t$$
Eliminate $t$
$$y=\frac{\cos^2 t}{\sin^2 t}=\frac{1-\sin^2 t}{\sin^2 t}\to y=\frac{1-x}{x}$$
the rectangular (cartesian) form of the curve is
$$y=\frac{1}{x}-1$$

Hope this is useful

Comment: yes, thank you, but i want to know how to explore and build graphic exactly in parametric form

Comment: @НазарТрухан Why?

Comment: because its my exercise for the calculation work in university